# How to get the full git reflog output when the output is pushed into a pipe

Tags: git, git-reflog

How can I get the output of `git reflog` into some other programs, without to copy+paste it. When I pipe the output, the branch names suddenly disappear:

```
$ git --no-pager reflog
8c394ee (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: commit: Bar
cbf7358 HEAD@{1}: commit (initial): Foo

$ git --no-pager reflog | cat
8c394ee HEAD@{0}: commit: Bar
cbf7358 HEAD@{1}: commit (initial): Foo
```

I just want to be able to `grep` for specific branch names in the output, which does not work, since git disables the branch names when I try to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git --no-pager reflog --decorate | cat
```

Comment: Unfortunately my clients (2.20.1 and 2.23.0.rc2.8.gff66981f45) don't understand --decorate

Comment: Sorry, my bad: it's `reflog --decorate`, not `git --decorate`.